# SQL Server : SELECT on inner join with multiple where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select some columns from two tables in a SQL Server database. I need to use something like the following:

```
SELECT 
    c.itmtxt, a.attr1val, a.attr2val, a.attr3val 
FROM 
    code c
JOIN 
    codeattribute a ON c.itmcd = a.itmcd 
WHERE 
    c.catcd = 1
    AND c.itmtxt = 2
    AND a.attr1val = 'A'
```

However, when I add the last where AND statements the query does not work. If I end with the single `WHERE` clause the code works as expected.

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data? The first things that come to mind are that your WHERE criteria don't match to existing data. Or, c.itmtxt may not be an integer data type.

Comment: or maybe you wanted `OR` in place of `AND`...

Comment: What are you not getting that you expected to get?

Comment: Basically, this returns more results than I want. I want to narrow down my results further by using more `where` clauses. But the comment about the integer data type is interesting. It may be a string. In that case, could I just surround it by 'quotes'?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move `AND a.attr1val = 'A'` into your join clause.

```
SELECT c.itmtxt, a.attr1val, a.attr2val, a.attr3val FROM code c
JOIN codeattribute a ON c.itmcd = a.itmcd AND a.attr1val = 'A'
WHERE c.catcd = 1
AND c.itmtxt = 2
```

Comment: This won't work because in `INNER JOIN` it doesn't matter where the filtering clause is added. Both `ON` and `WHERE` clause condition behaves in same manner. It's only with `OUTER JOINS` where the place of filter matter.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Deepshikha. I didn't realise that was the case.